# Emmet keyboard shortcuts not working in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, emmet

I'm not talking about the abreviations (which works fine); but rather keyboard shortcuts.

Like this [one](https://docs.emmet.io/actions/remove-tag/) for instance, Ctrl+k is supposed to remove a tag(opening and closing) and re-arrange the inner HTML's indentation.

This is just one example, but most shortcust found in emmet's page, doesnt work on vscode, why is that ? how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `Keyboard Shortcuts` page and search for emmet you will see many emmet commands unbound to a keybinding.  Including

`editor.emmet.action.removeTag`

[I think there are just too many emmet commands for vscode to have devoted keybindings to them when most people wouldn't use them.]

If you hover over any command and click on the `+` sign to its left vscode will open an input box where you can enter your desired shortcut keybinding.

I wouldn't recommend <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> as that is used as a part of a lot of default keybindings in vscode.

[image: emmet shortcut demo]